# map a dictionary on a list of dictionaries. How to optimize this without for loops?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

So I have a list of objects with attributes, but they can be treated as a dictionary.

So category_objects:

```
category_objects = [{"power": 10, "speed":2, "control":3}, {"power":2, "control":3, "speed":10}, {"power": 5, "control":3, "speed":-10}
```

And a dictionary with mapping to index. str-> int index

```
CAT_TO_IDX = {"power":0, "speed":1, "control":2}
```

The dictionaries consist of more elements, and the list is Long in reality.

Currently it's done in this way:

```
categories = []
    for category_object in category_objects:
        cats = []
        for c in SASB_CAT_NAME_TO_IDX.keys():
            cats.append(getattr(category_object, c))
        categories.append(cats)
```

Desired result:

```
categories = [[10, 2, 3], [2,10,3], [5,-10,3]]
```

**So the values of each category object, in order according to *CAT_TO_IDX*.**

I have been trying to speed up vectorizing slow parts of our operations, but I cannot figure out this one.
I ended up with this which is *basically the same code* and not much of a performance increase. Would want to find a way to vectorize or do it quickly with NumPy operations. Any idea how?

The ugly replacement code I tried..:

```
 def _num_key_apply(self, category_object, keys):
    return np.vectorize(category_object.__dict__.get)(keys)

 keys = np.array([*CAT_TO_IDX.keys(),], dtype=np.str)
 categories = [self._num_key_apply(category_object, keys) for category_object in category_objects]
```

Thank you! Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: "vectorize" usually means using `numpy` compiled methods.  But you have a list of dict, not arrays.  So "vectorize" (not even the `np.vectorize` function) does not apply.

Comment: You're making it more complicated than it needs to be: `[[d[k] for k in ("power", "speed", "control")] for d in category_objects]`.

Comment: You can also use Pandas to load up your list of dictionaries: `pd.DataFrame(category_objects, columns=["control", "power", "speed"])` or whatever order you want. The dictionaries in `category_objects` don't need to be in *any* particular order.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. I will remove that tag then, I'm just, in general, looking for a pretty and fast solution to this, because we do the above code many times and it seems like there should be a better and faster way to do it.

Comment: @ddejohn Yes, the nested list compression is of course an option. We do actually turn it into Dataframe later on so that suggestion is great! But for speed, whats the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that you *are* already using Pandas to put these data into a dataframe, you might as well take advantage of Pandas in the first place. You likely won't beat the performance by much, but it's fewer steps, which itself is an improvement in maintainability:

```py
import pandas as pd

desired_column_order = ["power", "speed", "control"]  # etc.
df = pd.DataFrame(category_objects, columns=desired_column_order)
```

Demos:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(category_objects, columns=["control", "power", "speed"])
   control  power  speed
0        3     10      2
1        3      2     10
2        3      5    -10

>>> pd.DataFrame(category_objects, columns=["speed", "control", "power"])
   speed  control  power
0      2        3     10
1     10        3      2
2    -10        3      5

>>> pd.DataFrame(category_objects, columns=["power", "speed", "control"])
   power  speed  control
0     10      2        3
1      2     10        3
2      5    -10        3
```

From here, you can "vectorize" operations on the numerical data, since Pandas is backed by numpy arrays. There is no "vectorization" for the loading of your data though. Vectorization depends on something called SIMD -- [single instruction, multiple data](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) -- which works by loading multiple data into a register, and then performing the *same* operation (like "multiply by 2" or "negate") on the entire register at the same time.

The `np.vectorize()` method is a glorified `for` loop -- it provides no benefits over a standard Python `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I will use your approach, readability wise it's great! Appreciated

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue. Glad to help.

Comment: `numpy` 'vectorization is anything that uses compiled numpy methods.  It doesn' matter whether those use SIMD or not (which is a compiler detail).

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` can streamline the regrouping:

```
In [44]: from collections import defaultdict
In [45]: dd=defaultdict(list)

In [47]: for d in category_objects:
    ...:     for k,v in d.items():
    ...:         dd[k].append(v)
    ...:         

In [48]: dd
Out[48]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'power': [10, 2, 5], 'speed': [2, 10, -10], 'control': [3, 3, 3]})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what OP wants though. If you look closely at their desired output, it's literally just the values of each separate dictionary, just in a specific order, hence why `[[d[k] for k in ("power", "speed", "control")] for d in category_objects]` is about as straightforward and simple as you can get to do what OP wants.

Comment: yes, there's another level of mapping that could easily be added.